# CoreData best practice implmentation on the UI side and in subproject

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

app scenario: on the UI, a button is tapped to get contact list from the server. the request goes to subproject which does the download and parsing and returns the result thru its delegate to the UI. so far everything works properly. lets say there is no internet connection and we cant have the contact list. to solve the problem, I want to cache the data in core data. if there is no internet, the cached data will be returned. now the question that bugs me, is it possible to create one data model and use it in subproject to save the data and in UI where data get pulled and edit from the same data model?
so basically i want to access core data from different subprojects and UI.
i couldnt find hints or tutorials regarding this issue. any ideas?

thanks in advance!

edit:

a project "b" that is added to the parent project "a". the project "b" is actually a static library.

if i let the library to do the saving and returning data to UI, wont it be inefficient to get all data from core data then send it to the UI?

i actually hope that there is a way to use same data model in both UI and the library.
i want prevent the UI to have huge load of data. its better to hace core data to handle that incl. memory mangement. i'm still reading some sources and trying to implement it on a test project.

Comment: What do you mean by subprojects?

Comment: a project "b" that is added to the parent project "a". the project "b" is actually a static library.

Comment: I assume you would just make the appropriate interface in your subproject - allowing direct access to the core data of a subproject sounds like a leaky abstraction

Comment: @Paul.s are you suggesting to use core data only with the library and send data as array to the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that only the main project should deal with persistency, as than you can always decide to handle it differently — save it permanently or not, use core data or a home grown sql wrapper…. So it would be up the the delegate to decide what to do with more data.
But along with the delegate protocol you could decide to maintain different model protocols that define, what your models can hold. this would be independent to the implementation. The delegate now could return objects — no matter if core data models or not — to the delegator if this objects conforms to the protocols. The delegator in the sub module now could check for values on the server and/or in the cache.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. what if the the core data is handled by a library. the UI and other libs should go thru that responsible lib. what do you think about this?

Comment: I think that it should be just responsible for core data or communication. otherwise you will create a monster module hard to maintain and to integrate in other projects. so nothing won. A module should guarantee 2 things: it does just one thing — but right and it defines clear interfaces.

Comment: yeah exactly i was worried about a monster module too. ok thanks. I'm still in favor of doing the coredata in one module. the reason i cant do it in the app delegate is that should work while transiting to the new static library. the critical point is that the app should be appstore ready anytime, even during development.

Comment: I said nothing about the app delegate

Comment: i guess i'm getting old and making up things in my head. :)
thanks for your ideas and suggestions